# SQL adding values to an existing result set at GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, resultset

A particular column of data within a table is being used to group my results set. Is it possible to add values to the GROUP BY without including them in the original data in order to force the grouping to display for values that don't exist.

[Here's my fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fdaa/1)

For example the table student contains a column called ks2 and this has the following values:

```
2a
3b
2a
4c
3b
```

A group by with a count would do this:

```
2a    2
3b    2
4c    1
```

But I would like to force it to include the value, for example, 4b in the results set:

```
2a    2
3b    2
4c    1
4b    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unusual request but you can apply a `union` trick.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92fa4/3

```
SELECT s.ks2,count(1)
FROM student s 
GROUP BY s.ks2
union
select '4b',0
from student s
```

Comment: EDIT: Hi thanks for this. The problem is if I say added '4c',0 to the union it would display two groupings for 4c. One of 4c, 0 and one of 4c, 2.

Comment: @Matt If you want the new entry added with union to be grouped then it's not possible to include 0 entry within group by it always count integer value 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
With s as (SELECT s.ks2 ad 'd'
FROM student s 
 union all 
select '4b' from student s)
Select d,count(d)
From s
Group by d
```